# Add Authentication inside AutoFac ConfigureTenant

Tags: asp.net-core, autofac

I would like to have Tenant Based Authentication on .NET Core App. I'm using AutoFac to build Tenant based Containers.

I was able to create a `ServiceCollection` and `Populate` the authentication services. However Authentication fails and getting Unauthorized response for the Tenant.

```
public static MultitenantContainer ConfigureMultitenantContainer(IContainer container)
{
    multitenantContainer.ConfigureTenant("80fdb3c0-5888-4295-bf40-ebee0e3cd8f3", containerBuilder =>
    {
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<DataService>().As<IDataService>().InstancePerDependency();
        containerBuilder.RegisterInstance(new OperationIdService()).SingleInstance();

        ServiceCollection tenantServices = new();
        tenantServices.AddAuthentication(opt =>
        {
            opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = "https://key-cloak.cloudapp.azure.com:8443/auth/realms/test";
            options.Audience = "test";
        });
        containerBuilder.Populate(tenantServices);
    });
    
    return multitenantContainer;
}
```

Comment: Have you dived into the ASP.NET side of things to see if, for example, it's resolving authentication settings just once and caching (so you don't get per tenant)? It's likely not just your DI setup causing the mismatch.

Comment: Also probably relevant - [`Populate` doesn't just convert registrations, it also sets up some default things](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection/blob/553f2881712d4cabe79a1dd121a147c01da65c8a/src/Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection/AutofacRegistration.cs#L96) for interacting with Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection. Have you tried manually registering the authentication things with Autofac and not using `Populate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it myself with the help of this article.

[MultiTenant Authentication by Michael McKenna](https://michael-mckenna.com/multi-tenant-asp-dot-net-core-application-tenant-specific-authentication/)

By default handlers aren’t registered using the default “.UseAuthentication” middleware. The schemes are registered in the middleware constructor before you have a valid tenant context. Since it doesn’t support registering schemes dynamically OOTB we will need to slightly modify it.

We’re going to take the existing `AuthenticationMiddleware.cs` and just move the `IAuthenticationSchemeProvider` injection point from the constructor to the Invoke method. Since the invoke method is called after we’ve registered our tenant services it will have all the tenant specific authentication services available to it now.